# smooth gentle transition when open content when clicked on button

Tags: javascript

As I added a button that opens content when clicked on it, the content just pops up straight away. But I'd like to add a smooth transition, where the content gently shows. This is the code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('.toggle').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).toggleClass('hidden show');
});
});
</script>
```

What needs to be added, please?

Comment: you need to add a transition to your hidden/show class. like this in your css:  `.show, .hidden{transition: 0.5s ease-in-out}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all those blocks (Except maybe one?) start closed, assign display:none to the css for the target blocks (probably what your hidden class does).

Since you are using jQuery already, the easiest way is to use either slideToggle() (http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) or fadeToggle() (http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) depending on the effect you are looking for instead of your current toggleClass.

```
 $(target).slideToggle();
```

Comment: Does not a CSS transition solve this problem? I think from smooth, user meant animated transition on changing classes.

Comment: If the idea is to simply fade it in, then it can be done with css transitions. the jquery solution is more crossbrowser compatible and doesn't require switching to height/visibility/opacity transition.

Comment: Yes, but I got he is asking about something like smooth animation, not easier toggling between classes. Jquery animation is an idea as well, but actually, we don't know what is he doing to do, then we can just provide the idea that by using "transitions" inside CSS you might get the effect you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your thoughts. Indeed i was just looking for a transition, so I decided to go for the css (as I guess the less js the better), using this:

```
#cb1 {position: absolute; left: -999em;}
label[for="cb1"] {cursor: pointer;}
#updates {max-height: 0; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; transition: 1s ease-in-out;}
#cb1:checked~#updates {max-height: 100%; opacity: 1;}
```